ValueError when trying to predict testing data in R neural network
I have my R code and prediction code which I cannot understand why I keep getting an error. The data is numerical data btw.
library(keras)
library(tensorflow)
NNmodel <- keras_model_sequential () %>%
  layer_dense(units=50,activation="relu",input_shape=ncol(x)) %>%
  layer_dropout(rate=0.2) %>%
  layer_dense(units=1)

NNmodel %>% compile(loss="mse", optimizer = optimizer_adam(), metrics = list("mean_absolute_error"))

#Fitting out NN model
history <- NNmodel %>% fit(x, y, epochs=50, batch_size=4, validation_data=list(model.matrix(val_x,val_y))

NN <- predict(NNmodel, x_test)

gives error when I run last line:
    ValueError: Missing data for input "dense_1_input". You passed a data dictionary with keys ['MSSubClass', 'LotArea', 'OverallQual', 'OverallCond', 'YearBuilt', 'YearRemodAdd', 'BsmtFinSF1', 'BsmtFinSF2', 'BsmtUnfSF', 'TotalBsmtSF', 'X1stFlrSF', 'X2ndFlrSF', 'LowQualFinSF', 'GrLivArea', 'BsmtFullBath', 'BsmtHalfBath', 'FullBath', 'HalfBath', 'BedroomAbvGr', 'KitchenAbvGr', 'TotRmsAbvGrd', 'Fireplaces', 'GarageCars', 'GarageArea', 'WoodDeckSF', 'OpenPorchSF', 'EnclosedPorch', 'X3SsnPorch', 'ScreenPorch', 'PoolArea', 'MiscVal', 'MoSold', 'YrSold']. Expected the following keys: ['dense_1_input']

